# Restore SQL 2008 database fails with error on page xxx:xxx

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

This is the situation:

Got a full backup (.bak file) of a SQL 2008 database, with partitions.
The .bak file is 100gb.

I need to restore this database on a different server, to a new database.
So, command is like this:

```
Restore Database [newname] FROM DISK= N'D:\mydatabase.bak' WITH FILE = 1
MOVE 'mydatabasename' TO 'C:\mydatabase.mdf'
MOVE 'Partition1' TO 'C:\`mydatabase_1.ndf'
etc..
STATS = 1
```

After 52 percent processed, I get this error:

```
Msg 3183, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
RESTORE detected an error on page (8481:555819297) in database "dbname" as read from the backup set.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Before all default suggestions come up, this is what I have already done:

- Checkdb on original database --> no errors
- Restore the .bak file on my local machine --> no errors, so the backup is correct.

What can I do to troubleshoot this? How can I get to the actual problem?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: do you copy the bakup file to target server before restore or try to restore from some windows shared folder?

Comment: Yes, first copy the bak to target server, then restore.

Comment: Have you checked the checksum of the file after you copy it onto the target server? Maybe there is an error (perhaps caused by a disk error)? Check the MD5 of the version that you can restore against this version. Are they the same?

Comment: i think the question can be resolved faster on serverfault q&a site (http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @Dommer: I copied the file rarred in multiple files. On target server, I extracted the file correctly, so the .bak file should be good I guess?
@Heximal, i'll try that, thanks.

Comment: You should still check the file after you unpack. What if, for example, you unpacked it onto a bit of hard disk with a fault?

Comment: I did a Restore VerifyOnly now on the extracted .bak file, and that says 'The backup set on file 1 is valid.'

Comment: Have you run dbcc on the copy you restored to your local machine? Have you tried doing a backup from your local machine and then moving that onto the ultimate target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to restore the backup on other servers.

After a while, we switched over to a new server. 
The old one with the errors is on a test bench now.

Conclusion is that the backup file was correct, and the problem lies in a hardware problem on the server. Probably disk problemens, but when thats clear, i will post it here..

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check the MD5 checksums of the .bak as created on the server and after it's been moved to the new home. I'll bet something small got tweaked in your copy as you moved it over; something in your process, maybe just a network hiccup, borked something or other.

Few MD5 checksum utilities here: http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/free-md5-sum-tools.shtml

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

yeah for such restoration errors the problem lies in the drive from where you are trying to restore the backup,try changing the drive (e.g d to e )..it worked for me.

one can also try attaching mdf file directly.